# Pandas Summing Two Columns with Nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have three columns in pandas dataframes with Nan:

```
>>> d=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3':[5,6]})
>>> d
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
>>> d['col2'].iloc[0]=np.nan
>>> d
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   NaN     5
1     2   4.0     6
>>> d['col1'].iloc[1]=np.nan
>>> d
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   NaN     5
1   NaN   4.0     6
>>> d['col3'].iloc[1]=np.nan
>>> d
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   NaN   5.0
1   NaN   4.0   NaN
```

Now, I would like the column addition to have the following output:

```
>>> d['col1']+d['col3']
0    6.0
1    NaN

>>> d['col1']+d['col2']
0   1.0
1   4.0
```

However, in reality, the output is instead:

```
>>> d['col1']+d['col3']
0    6.0
1    NaN

>>> d['col1']+d['col2']
0   NaN
1   NaN
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) to get your sums, with `fill_value=0`:

```
>>> d.col1.add(d.col2, fill_value=0)
0    1.0
1    4.0
dtype: float64

>>> d.col1.add(d.col3, fill_value=0)
0    6.0
1    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

When adding columns one and two, use `Series.add` with `fill_value=0`.

```
>>> d
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   NaN   5.0
1   NaN   4.0   NaN
>>> 
>>> d['col1'].add(d['col2'], fill_value=0)
0    1.0
1    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Dataframes and series have methods like `add`, `sub`, ... in order to perform more sophisticated operations than the associated operators `+`, `-`, ... can provide.

The methods may take additional arguments that finetune the operation.